# WPF: (SplitButton) MouseLeave won't fire without a click

Tags: wpf, mouseleave, split-button

I working on a WPF Ribbon application using a third party source (Syncfusion).
In my application I have a SplitButton with several CheckBoxes in it, I'm trying to implement MouseHover like action to my SplitButton so that on MouseEnter the DropDown will open and on MouseLeave the DropDown will close.

MouseEnter works great.

MouseLeave works great on a regular button (for changing the background for example) but on SplitButton it won't fire unless I press on the mouse (left or right button - it doesn't matter).

Any chance I could close the DropDown upon leaving the SplitButton without clicking on the mouse? Maybe by using another event?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: WPF don't have splitbutton (Except RibbonSplitButton). Do you use it from other source (codepack, third party source,...)?

Comment: I'm using a SplitButton from Syncfusion, for my WPF Ribbon application.

Comment: Okay. You should say (edit) it in your question. Otherwise people don't know how to answer you.

Comment: Have you tried implementing MouseLeave handler without implementing MouseEnter handler just for testing?

Comment: I tried that right now. MouseLeave working great without MouseEnter. 
They just won't work together.

Comment: Probably means that your MouseEnter implementation somehow messes up the logic of the framework or prevents it from logging that the mouse is within the control. Do you set `e.Handled = false;` in MouseEnter handler ? BTW, if you want me to respond quickly, you need to tag me using @ sign.